# INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK error on Novo 7 Paladin tablet (ICS 4.01)

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android

I try to deploy the Google IO Schedule app (http://code.google.com/p/iosched/), which runs fine on Motorola Xoom tablet (ICS 4.03), on my Nexus One (2.3), on emulator.

However, when I try to run it on Novo 7 Padalin Tablet (ICS 4.01), I'm getting the message INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK .

Below is the log when I try to deploy the app (app package name differs from original Google IO name, but it's the same app).

Somebody else has reported this issue before, and it was posted at LiveCode forum, but since StackOverflow is quite popular, I thought to give it a short for an eventual solution. Or maybe it's a problem with this specific tablet/Android stack.

http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=10606&p=50837#p50837

(I have the latest Android ICS SDK, on Mac OS X Lion.)

App manifest: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/AndroidManifest.xml

Error log:

http://pastebin.com/jhGhRsv7

```
Target device: Novo7 Paladin
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/user/Projects/USJ/mo.edu.usj.cis.android/out/production/mo.edu.usj.cis.android/mo.edu.usj.cis.android.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android
Installing mo.edu.usj.cis.android
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]


D/AndroidRuntime( 2502): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 2502): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 2502): CheckJNI is OFF
D/AndroidRuntime( 2502): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
I/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): hello +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android --- /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android ---(null) ok
D/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): Comparing ABIs mips  versus README.txt
D/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): abi didn't match anything: README.txt (end at -1)
I/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): hello +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android --- /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android ---(null) ok
D/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): Comparing ABIs armeabi  versus README.txt
D/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): abi didn't match anything: README.txt (end at -1)
I/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): hello +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android --- /data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android ---(null) ok
D/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): Comparing ABIs armeabi-v7a  versus README.txt
D/NativeLibraryHelper( 1172): abi didn't match anything: README.txt (end at -1)
W/ActivityManager(  130): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android
D/dalvikvm( 1172): GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 8% free 6905K/7431K, paused 1ms+2ms
W/ActivityManager(  130): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/mo.edu.usj.cis.android
D/dalvikvm(  130): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1159K, 11% free 11705K/13127K, paused 3ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm(  130): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 755K, 11% free 11703K/13127K, paused 64ms
D/dalvikvm(  130): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 732K, 11% free 11703K/13127K, paused 63ms
D/dalvikvm(  130): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 739K, 11% free 11710K/13127K, paused 64ms
E/PackageManager(  130): ---------------------------------in else if /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk---/data/data/mo.edu.usj.cis.android/lib
I/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): hello +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk --- /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk ---(null) ok
D/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): Comparing ABIs mips  versus README.txt
D/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): abi didn't match anything: README.txt (end at -1)
I/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): hello +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk --- /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk ---(null) ok
D/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): Comparing ABIs armeabi  versus README.txt
D/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): abi didn't match anything: README.txt (end at -1)
I/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): hello +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk --- /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk ---(null) ok
D/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): Comparing ABIs armeabi-v7a  versus README.txt
D/NativeLibraryHelper(  130): abi didn't match anything: README.txt (end at -1)
E/PackageManager(  130): ---------------------------------  NativeLibraryHelper.copyNativeBinariesIfNeededLI err! 
W/PackageManager(  130): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/mo.edu.usj.cis.android-1.apk
D/dalvikvm(  130): GC_EXPLICIT freed 158K, 12% free 11678K/13127K, paused 4ms+11ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 2502): Shutting down VM
I/AndroidRuntime( 2502): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/dalvikvm( 2502): GC_CONCURRENT freed 123K, 78% free 465K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
D/jdwp    ( 2502): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
D/dalvikvm( 2502): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 689K, 64% free 9355K/25607K, paused 2ms+6ms
I/EventLogService(  223): Aggregate from 1327891093093 (log), 1327891093093 (data)
D/dalvikvm(  223): GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 9% free 7614K/8327K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled across this old question while searching, so am answering it in case it's useful to anyone else in the future.

The error in the install is the NativeLibraryHelper failing to find an appropriate native library to install.

The Novo 7 Paladin has a MIPS processor (to save on cost) and at the time this question was posted the Android SDK did not support the MIPS architecture for native binaries out of the box (it does now though).  The Google I/O app is all Java but it has several dependencies and I assume one of them (probably the Android 4 support library) includes a native binary.